# Convertir Fechas en MySQL

Tags: mysql, date

¿Cómo puedo convertir una fecha 2019-09-06 a 201909 en `MySQL`?

Intenté con esto sin tener resultados:

```
SELECT str_to_date(`fec`,'%m/%d/%Y') FROM user
```

Comment: el formato correcto a usar debe ser "%Y%m%d" para obtener el formato que deseas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si su columna `fec` ya es una fecha, puede usar [`DATE_FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) asi:

```
SELECT date_format(fec,'%m%d%Y') FROM user
```

Comment: muchas gracias me sirvio!!

Answer (score 4):

Para cambiar el formato de fechas en MyQL se usa el [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format), si el valor que deseas convertir es  `2019-09-06` y deseas convertirlo a `20190906` usa el formato  `"%Y%m%d"`, ejemplo:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT("2019-09-06", "%Y%m%d")
```

salida:

```
20190906
```

---

Aplicando lo anterior a tu query, se realizaría de esta forma:

```
SELECT date_format(fec,"%Y%m%d") FROM user
```